# How to find the frequency that a specific entity occurs in an SQL table?

Tags: sql

I have a question for a school assignment that gives us the following data:

```sql
insert into vehicles values ('U200', 'Chevrolet', 'Camaro', 1969, 'red');
insert into vehicles values ('U201', 'Toyoto', 'Corolla', 2012, 'red');
insert into vehicles values ('U202', 'Toyoto', 'RAV4', 2013, 'red');
insert into vehicles values ('U203', 'Kia', 'Cube', 2013, 'red');
insert into vehicles values ('U300', 'Mercedes', 'SL 230', 1964, 'black');
insert into vehicles values ('U301', 'Audi', 'A4', 2013, 'black');
insert into vehicles values ('U302', 'Toyoto', 'RAV4', 2012, 'black');
insert into vehicles values ('U303', 'Mercedes', 'SL 230', 2014, 'black');
insert into vehicles values ('U400', 'Chevrolet', 'Camaro', 2012, 'black');
```

EDIT: I trimmed down some of the data since it made the question too long. I think the idea is still clear without all the data values entered.

---

We're tasked with finding for each year of a car, find the most frequent make and the most frequent car color. In case of ties, list all those ties.

We're given this table and we're supposed to make a query for this data that answers the question.

vehicles(vin,make,model,year,color)

---

I tried to use 'join' or 'group by' to somehow group everything together, but I have no idea if my methodology even makes sense. I tried something like the code I have here, but I'm kinda lost on how the rest should function.

---

```
select year, make, color, count(make)
from vehicles

where (Not sure what to put here)...

order by year desc

having count(*)
```

---

The expected result should be something like this:

```
1964|Mercedes|black

1969|Chevrolet|red

1969|Chevrolet|white

2012|Chevrolet|white

2012|Toyoto|white

2013|Audi|red

2014|Audi|white

2015|Audi|white

2016|Audi|white
```

Comment: Your sample data and output don't seem to line up.  To be clear, are you saying that for every year _and_ car manufacturer, you want the car with the color occurring the most?  Note that your sample data is a bit thin.

Comment: MySQL & SQL server both are not same.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Essentially, I want to check for each specific year that there was a car, which car brand occurred the most that year and which color occurred the most that year as well. I forgot to add some data, so I modified it to include the remaining data.

Comment: If you are "tasked" to do this, is it homework?  Should you use common / standard SQL, or are you allowed to use keywords and techniques unique to sqlite?  Also, we could simply write you a query to order, but that is not the traditional approach to just write complete code, but there are various aspects of such aggregates queries that should come with a tutorial... something also not appropriate to Stack Overflow.  Can you show us more of what you have tried.  Do you understand the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: @CS_Student45 . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

Your description and comments imply that you want something this:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY year, make) make_count,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY year, color) color_count
    FROM vehicles
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY make_count DESC) make_rnk,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY color_count DESC) color_rnk
    FROM cte1
)

SELECT year, make, color
FROM cte2
WHERE 1 IN (make_rnk, color_rnk)
ORDER BY year, make;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need two queries (although they could be combined as below) as I understand the question although, each year of a car is confusing, so this is based on for each year.

As such I believe that the following will do what you appear to want :-

```
WITH 
    colour_year_counts AS (SELECT colour, year, count() AS c FROM vehicles GROUP BY year, colour)
SELECT * FROM colour_year_counts AS cyctrim  WHERE c >= (SELECT max(c) FROM colour_year_counts WHERE year = cyctrim.year) ORDER BY year;

WITH 
    car_make_counts AS (SELECT make,year,count() AS c FROM vehicles GROUP BY year, make)
SELECT * FROM car_make_counts AS cmctrim WHERE c >= (SELECT max(c) FROM car_make_counts WHERE year = cmctrim.year) ORDER BY year;
```

This results in :-

For colour :-

[image]

For make :-

[image]

The following combines the two into a single query :-

```
WITH 
    colour_year_counts AS (SELECT colour, year, count() AS c FROM vehicles GROUP BY year, colour),
    trimmedcyc AS (SELECT * FROM colour_year_counts AS cyctrim  WHERE c >= (SELECT max(c) FROM colour_year_counts WHERE year = cyctrim.year) ORDER BY year),

    car_make_counts AS (SELECT make,year,count() AS c FROM vehicles GROUP BY year, make),
    trimmedcmc AS (SELECT * FROM car_make_counts AS cmctrim WHERE c >= (SELECT max(c) FROM car_make_counts WHERE year = cmctrim.year) ORDER BY year),

  report AS (
        SELECT 'Colour' AS Item ,'Year' AS Year,'Count' AS Count, 0 AS sortorder
        UNION SELECT *, 1 AS sortorder FROM trimmedcyc
        UNION SELECT 'Make','','', 2 as sortorder
        UNION SELECT *, 3 AS sortorder FROM trimmedcmc
    )
SELECT Item,Year,Count FROM report ORDER BY sortorder,year;
```

and results in :-

[image]

- Note The line that Appears as Item Year Count not part of the output, but the column names as shown by the tool.